# CAML query in JSOM for SharePoint 2013 results in "value does not fall in the expected range"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query, jsom

While querying yes/no column using caml query JSOM sharepoint 2013 getting "value doesnot fall in the excpeted range".

```
 <ProjectedFields>
 <Field Name="DateColumn" Type="Lookup" List="Employee_Table" ShowField="DateColumn" />
 <Field Name="yes_noColumn" Type="Lookup" List="Employee_Table" ShowField="yes_noColumn" />
  </ProjectedFields
  <FieldRef Name="DateColumn"/> 
  <FieldRef Name="yes_noColumn"/>
  <Query>
  <Where>
  <Or>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="yes_noColumn"/><Value Type="Boolean">true</Value>        </Eq>
  <Leq><FieldRef Name="DateColumn"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-180" /></Value></Leq> 
  </Or>
  </Where>
  </Query>
  </View>
```

If I remove this yes/no column type from condition and put some "text" type column it is working. Am getting error for thr type "yes/no" column.

I tried with

```
Boolean --> true

Boolean --> True

Boolean --> TRUE

Boolean --> 1

Integer --> 1

bit --> 1
```

None of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint join has some limitations. You can check [here is this blog](https://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/limitations-of-the-sharepoint-join-using-caml/). It seems that Boolean fields is not supported. Hope this helps.

But Calculated fields are supported. So you could try create calculated column with value of your `boolean` column (like, 1/0), store it as text value, and then you could try query by this calculated column.

Comment: It is not working when we join two lists.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. I have lookup, yes/no columns for filter is there any solution for that. ?

Comment: I updated my answer again.

Comment: You are awesome !!!!! thanks alot its working for me.